# httpwebresponse doesnt work

Tags: httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I'm trying to programmatically search for an item on the said website.

Following does not work for me. Response is actually an error page, instead of the search result page.

Pls help.

```
        string sUrl = "http://www.arrownac.com/";
        string sUrl1 = "http://app.arrownac.com/aws/pg_webc?s=P";

        HttpWebRequest owebreq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sUrl1);
        owebreq.Referer = sUrl;          

        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();

        string postdata = "search_token=" + "743C083102JPTR";
        byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postdata);

        owebreq.ContentType = "text/html";
            //"application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        owebreq.Method = "POST";
        owebreq.ContentLength = data.Length;
        Stream newStream = owebreq.GetRequestStream();
        newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        newStream.Close();        

        HttpWebResponse owebresp = (HttpWebResponse)owebreq.GetResponse();
        string sResult = string.Empty;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(owebresp.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            sResult = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Uhm, what doesn't work? Have you debugged it? Do you get errors, if so what error (if page what is the code)? Tell something more about your problem or you won't get good answers!

Comment: there is no code errors, it executes fine. However I get response output as     <!-- Vignette V6 Wed Oct 13 08:58:23 2010 --> <html> <head> <title>Arrow Electronics : Error Occured</title> <script language="JavaScript"> self.location="/aws/pg_error"; </script> </head> </html>     manually if I go to http://www.arrownac.com/ and enter part and search POST action is mapped to http://app.arrownac.com/aws/pg_webc?s=P, and it fetches the results. 743C083102JPTR is a sample part with which search can be made to see the results.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not sending the request *exactly* as the website expects it. I would do the following:

```
1) use firefox.
2) install firebug plugin
3) use firefox to execute your scenario.
4) Look at the actual requests sent from firefox (use the firebug plugin for that)
5) Now, duplicate the exact same requests, down to the user-agent,cookies and request headers in code.
6) profit?
```

Answer (score 0):

Why writing so much code when it can be simple:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            var referer = "http://www.arrownac.com/";
            client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Referer] = referer;                
            var valuesToPost = new NameValueCollection
            {
                { "search_token", "743C083102JPTR" },
            };
            var url = "http://app.arrownac.com/aws/pg_webc?s=P";
            var result = client.UploadValues(url, valuesToPost);
            var resultString = Encoding.Default.GetString(result);
            Console.WriteLine(resultString);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry no luck, result is same as my code's; looks like target site doesnt take POST from external programs, not sure how to override.